# How can you re-render a page from JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, render, swap

I am not quite sure if that's the correct way to phrase it, but here is [my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/yr9cn0rw/2/)

As you can see, pretty simple code:

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div></div>
```

What I want to achieve is:

1. You click on the `div` with the *first* class, it will swap that class with the sibling element
2. You click the sibling element, and it swaps it back, so you just swap classes around 2 elements

The problem here is it works correctly only the first time, and the second time when the new element receives the class via `addClass`, jQuery doesn't recognize that it contains the class by the first page load? How can I resolve this?

P.S: I made a `console.log(111);` just to make sure, and sure enough it triggers ONLY when I click on the black `div` after the first swap (the one that SHOULD NOT have the *first* class anymore)

Comment: I think JQuery is unable to reparse the DOM without explicitly tolding it to do so. At document ready, only the first div had class "first", and it stays that way. You could try a function that parses all the DOM in search of the "first" class. Maybe Vanilla JS is more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this behavior, you can use delegated events http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ on elements wrapper;

```
$(document).delegate('.first', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(123);
    $(this).removeClass('first');
   $(this).siblings().addClass('first');
})
```

Comment: If you have only two children, this is the answer you seek

Comment: What default action are you preventing with `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Just a copy paste to minimize difference between question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple way to do it is this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var first = $('.first');
  var second = first.next();
  first.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    first.removeClass('first');
    second.addClass('first');
  });
  second.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    second.removeClass('first');
    first.addClass('first');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.first {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first"></div>
<div></div>
```

This way does not scale well.

Your problem was you only change when you click the `$(first)` which does not change when clicked it's still point to the first div.

A better way with vanilla javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('first')) {
    e.target.classList.remove('first')
    var sibling = getNextSibling(e.target) || getPreviousSibling(e.target)
    if (sibling) {
      sibling.classList.add('first')
    }
  }
})

function getNextSibling(elem) {
  var sibling = elem.nextSibling 
  while(sibling && sibling.nodeType != 1) {
    sibling = sibling.nextSibling
  }
  return sibling
}

function getPreviousSibling(elem) {
  var sibling = elem.previousSibling 
  while(sibling && sibling.nodeType != 1) {
    sibling = sibling.previousSibling
  }
  return sibling
}
```

Comment: You need to add jquery to your sandbox demo.  This is also not really the way to solve this problem.

Comment: @JonSG i fixed that, I mentioned that it's the best solution. i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is push both items into an array, then flip between indexes on click.

```js
var elems = [];
$(document).on("click", ".first", function(event) {
   elems = elems.length == 0 ? [event.originalEvent.target, $(event.originalEvent.target).next()] : elems;
  $(elems[event.originalEvent.target === elems[0] ? 1 : 0]).addClass("first");
  $(elems[event.originalEvent.target === elems[0] ? 0 : 1]).removeClass("first");
});
```

```css
.first {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">x</div>
<div>y</div>
```